# Sass and Haml syntax highlighting in Geany (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, syntax-highlighting, geany

I'm using Sass (**not SCSS**) and Haml, and I'd like them to be syntax highlighted in Geany rather than appear as plain text. Is there a way to enable or install this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed on the mailing list ( http://lists.geany.org/pipermail/users/2012-October/008346.html ):

> Scintilla version in Git Geany supports S*C*SS, just set the
>   lexer.css.scss.language CSS lexer property to 1.  I don't know SASS and HAML, but I don't think Scintilla have those yet, as Lex said.

reading the related Scintilla posting ( https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/scintilla-interest/QiC_5vvfXk0 ) seems to indicate that a HAML Lexer was never finished.